# How to deploy smart contract in ink which constructor takes value in params

Tags: ink, rust, astar

I have written an erc20 smart contract in ink(Rust). The contract has been compiled successfully. But I got an error while deploying my smart contract. Basically, the contract constructor takes total_spply as a parameter. So, how to pass this value while deploying a smart contract using swanky-cli?

This command I am using to deploy smart contract:

swanky contract deploy erc20 --account alice -g 10000000000 -a true

This is my constructor.

```
  pub fn new(total_supply: Balance) -> Self {
        let mut balances = Mapping::default();
        let caller = Self::env().caller();
        balances.insert(&caller, &total_supply);

        Self::env().emit_event(Transfer {
            from: None,
            to: Some(caller),
            value: total_supply,
        });

        Self {
            total_supply,
            balances,
            allowances: Default::default(),
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your constructor takes `Balance` as an arg, not a boolean.
What about passing some initial value for e.g. `-a 1000000`?

Comment: @Shunsuke Thank you so much. The error has been gone.

Comment: Please provide the answer to your question or close it.

Answer (score 3):

Constructor takes `Balance` instead of boolean.
So, you need to pass some Balance value via swanky command.
E.g. `swanky contract deploy erc20 --account alice -g 10000000000 -a 10000000`